# Implementing node js in existing php+laravel+mysql project

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5

I have been searching a lot about integrating node js in the existing laravel project, but I couldn't find any appropriate link or reference which will guide me the actual execution.

However my first question is whether is it really feasible or not?

Basically, we have a php+laravel+mysql application, and now we are at the stage where we want to show many events/updates/functionality on real time basis.

So, I was wondering whether we can take the advantage of event driven node js technology to accomplish our requirement.

Any suggestions on where to start or how to do it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So...sockets...You can start by implementing locally (worker+redis+socket server) and then configure the host where the application is stored (reverse proxy for the socket endpoint would be required if you have SSL)...configure redis...workers with supervisord (in the docs)...

Comment: Why do you think you need nodeJS exactly? It's just another server-side language, equivalent to PHP. Almost certainly anything you want to do using nodeJS can be achieve using PHP as well. You mention "real-time event-driven" functionality...are you talking about websockets? Websockets are not exclusive to NodeJS, although many people seem to be under the mistaken impression that they are. There are existing implementations of websockets (and server-sent events) for PHP which you can use. Don't overcomplicate your project by using multiple different server-side languages.

Comment: @ADyson

Thanks for your response, I will definitely look into it.

Basically, we are consuming different different 3rd party APIs in our application. Event is triggered on our page and the operation happens at the 3rd party API level, once the operation gets completed they trigger our web hook to update the response in our back-end. So basically we want to notify (or perform some operations) our front-end user (without page refresh) as soon as we get the web hook update from API.

Comment: please read: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting and https://pusher.com/ and https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Ok thanks for the detail. All of that should be achievable using PHP as the back-end. The links in the comment above may be of use to you as well as your own research.